# Populate Observable collection from XML file in project (WPF)

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, observablecollection

I Have XML file in my project

Here is it

```
  <?xml version="1.0"?>
<catalog>
   <car id="1">
      <model>Scoda Fabia</model>
      <year>2011</year>
      <producer>Folkwagen</producer>
      <price>6000</price>
      <owner>Bil Johnson</owner>
      <tel>+5810456455456</tel>
      <mileage>670000</mileage>
      <registered>USA</registered>
      <image>Fabia1.JPG</image>
   </car>
   <car id="2">
      <model>Huindai Getz</model>
      <year>2008</year>
      <producer>Huindai</producer>
      <price>5000</price>
      <owner>Dimitrious Gregorakis</owner>
      <tel>+5810456445456</tel>
      <mileage>120000</mileage>
      <registered>USA</registered>
      <image>hyundai_getz2.jpg</image>
   </car>
   <car id="3">
      <model>Huindai i108</model>
      <year>2014</year>
      <producer>Huindai</producer>
      <price>15000</price>
      <owner>Dex Dexter</owner>
      <tel>+5815556445456</tel>
      <mileage>30000</mileage>
      <registered>Canada</registered>
      <image>hyundaii108.jpg</image>
   </car>
   <car id="4">
      <model>Aveo</model>
      <year>2000</year>
      <producer>Shevrole</producer>
      <price>3500</price>
      <owner>Ivan Ivanov</owner>
      <tel>+5815556445477</tel>
      <mileage>300000</mileage>
      <registered>Mexico</registered>
      <image>aveo.jpg</image>
   </car>
</catalog>
```

I created a class from it, here is code for class

```
 [XmlRoot(ElementName = "car")]
public class Car
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "model")]
    public string Model { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "year")]
    public string Year { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "producer")]
    public string Producer { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "price")]
    public string Price { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "owner")]
    public string Owner { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "tel")]
    public string Tel { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "mileage")]
    public string Mileage { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "registered")]
    public string Registered { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "image")]
    public string Image { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "id")]
    public string Id { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName = "catalog")]
public class Catalog
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "car")]
    public List<Car> Car { get; set; }
}
```

And Created ViewModel for it, where I defined observable collection anв define a method to fill it with data from XML

```
public class CarViewModel
{
    public ObservableCollection<List<Car>> car { get; set; }
    public void LoadCars()
    {
        Car = new ObservableCollection<List<Car>>();

        var path = @"xml\CarsDatabase.xml";
        using (TextReader reader = new StreamReader(path))
        {
            XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Catalog));
            return (Catalog)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
        }
    }
}
```

In method LoadCars I need to fill car observable collections with data in my file, that is inside of the project.

How I can do this correctly?
Thank's for help.

**UPDATE**

I try to use this method

```
public void LoadCars()
    {
        Car = new ObservableCollection<List<Car>>();

        var path = @"xml\CarsDatabase.xml";
        using (TextReader reader = new StreamReader(path))
        {
            XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Catalog));
            return (Catalog)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
        }
    }
```

But now I have error

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error   CS0127  Since 'CarViewModel.LoadCars()' returns void, a return keyword must not be followed by an object expression DaxxTest    C:\Users\nemes\Source\Repos\daxx_test\DaxxTest\DaxxTest\ViewModels\CarViewModel.cs  25  Active

Comment: I updated code in question, added loading XML File@mjwills

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to Deserialize XML document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/364253/how-to-deserialize-xml-document)

Comment: Do you really mean `ObservableCollection<List<Car>>` and not, say, `List<Car>` or `ObservableCollection<Car>`?

Comment: I edited this `public ObservableCollection<Car> Car { get; set; }` of course @fuglede

Comment: Hi, 
"Car = new ObservableCollection<List<Car>>();": should be "car" 
and change ObservableCollection<List<Car>> to  ObservableCollection<Car>. in both. 
P/S: you can copy paste my answer to check it.
Cheer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
public ObservableCollection<List<Car>> car { get; set; }
```

to

```
public ObservableCollection<Car> car { get; set; }
```

And use XmlSerializer to serialize your xml information. Check bellow code for an example:

```
        public ObservableCollection<Car> cars { get; set; }

        public void LoadCars()
        {

            XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Catalog));

            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader("CarsDatabase.xml");
            var catalog = (Catalog)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
            cars = new ObservableCollection<Car>(catalog.Car);
            reader.Close();
        }

        [Serializable()]
        public class Car
        {
            [XmlElement(ElementName = "model")]
            public string Model { get; set; }
            [XmlElement(ElementName = "year")]
            public string Year { get; set; }
            [XmlElement(ElementName = "producer")]
            public string Producer { get; set; }
            [XmlElement(ElementName = "price")]
            public string Price { get; set; }
            [XmlElement(ElementName = "owner")]
            public string Owner { get; set; }
            [XmlElement(ElementName = "tel")]
            public string Tel { get; set; }
            [XmlElement(ElementName = "mileage")]
            public string Mileage { get; set; }
            [XmlElement(ElementName = "registered")]
            public string Registered { get; set; }
            [XmlElement(ElementName = "image")]
            public string Image { get; set; }
            [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "id")]
            public string Id { get; set; }
        }

        [Serializable()]
        [XmlRootAttribute("catalog", Namespace = "", IsNullable = false)]
        public class Catalog
        {
            [XmlElement(ElementName = "car")]
            public List<Car> Car { get; set; }
        }
```

Comment: Okay, But I also have Catalog, maybe I need to use it?

Comment: You already used it to serialize your cars list. 
In case you need to use your Catalog some where, you can define other property/variable.

Comment: Yeah, but when I try to run code in main class like this
`var carViewModel = new CarViewModel();
            carViewModel.LoadCars();
            DataContext = carViewModel;`

Data context is null.

Comment: Interesting!  Could you please share your mainclass and xaml also?
I tried from my side: public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            var carViewModel = new CarViewModel();
            carViewModel.LoadCars();
            this.DataContext = carViewModel;
        }               
    }
And it worked well

Comment: My problem is that system cannot find file

Comment: : 'Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Users\nemes\source\repos\daxx_test\DaxxTest\DaxxTest\bin\Debug\xml\CarsDatabase.xml'.'

Comment: Set the xml file as "Copy if newer" or you can copy-paste the xml file to "C:\Users\nemes\source\repos\daxx_test\DaxxTest\DaxxTest\bin\Debug\xml\"

Comment: It 's great when it can help you! Could you please check the answer as resolved? Thanks!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177920/discussion-between-nhan-phan-and-eugene-sukh).